# Insert if table is empty OR join condition is fulfilled

Tags: mysql, sql

Nice puzzle for hardcore SQLers.

2 tables: auctions and bids.

```
CREATE TABLE auctions
(
id BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
created_at INT,
timer INT DEFAULT 10,
user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE bids
(
id BIGINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
created_at INT,
user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED,
auction_id BIGINT UNSIGNED
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Given an auction, a user can place a bid on it if ONE of the following conditions is satisfied:

- the last bid was created less then auction.timer seconds ago
- no bids are present for the auction

In poor terms: it's a game where the last bidding user not followed by anyone within x seconds wins the auction.

No transactions allowed here.

Here is my try:

```
INSERT INTO bids (user_id, auction_id) 
SELECT 1, a.id
FROM auctions AS a, bids AS b
WHERE a.id = b.auction_id
AND a.user_id IS NULL
AND a.id = 1
AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - b.created_at) < a.timer
LIMIT 1
```

It works but I don't know how to put the "OR no bids are present for the given auction id" logic inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need an outer join (optional) to bids.  Like so:

```
INSERT INTO bids (user_id, auction_id) 
SELECT 1, a.id
FROM auctions AS a
left outer join bids AS b
ON a.id = b.auction_id
AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - b.created_at) < a.timer
where
(a.user_id IS NULL
AND a.id = 1

) OR
b.id IS NULL     --this will be true if there is no bid present
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Here the solution (question marks for parameters):INSERT INTO bids (user_id, auction_id) 
SELECT ?, a.id
FROM auctions AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN bids AS b
ON a.id = b.auction_id
WHERE a.user_id IS NULL
AND a.id = ?
AND 
 ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - b.created_at) < a.timer OR b.id IS NULL)
LIMIT 1

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery to determine if any bids have been placed in an auction.  Perhaps something like:

```
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM bids WHERE auction_id = ?)
```

Comment: thank you brian, but would the query be atomic with this subquery in it?

Comment: Probably not, but I don't think a JOIN would be atomic either.  You'll probably have to lock the tables first.